# Error trying to read csv file

Tags: c#, csv

Good Day,

i am having trouble reading csv files on my asp.net project.

it always returns the error index out of range cannot find column 6

before i go on explaining what i did here is the code:

```
                string savepath;  
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
                savepath = context.Server.MapPath("files");
                string filename = postedFile.FileName;
                todelete = savepath + @"\" + filename;
                string forex = savepath + @"\" + filename;
                postedFile.SaveAs(savepath + @"\" + filename);
                DataTable tblcsv = new DataTable();
                tblcsv.Columns.Add("latitude");
                tblcsv.Columns.Add("longitude");
                tblcsv.Columns.Add("mps");
                tblcsv.Columns.Add("activity_type");
                tblcsv.Columns.Add("date_occured");
                tblcsv.Columns.Add("details");
                string ReadCSV = File.ReadAllText(forex);

                foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
                    {
                        //Adding each row into datatable  
                        tblcsv.Rows.Add();
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split('-'))
                        {
                            tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }


                }
```

i tried using comma separated columns but the string that comes with it contains comma so i tried the - symbol just to make sure that there are no excess commas on the text file but the same error is popping up.

am i doing something wrong?

thank you in advance

Comment: May we know in which line you got the exception?

Comment: @khlr it is `String.Split` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it's here tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;

Comment: csvRow.Split('-') check the length of array , it is more than 6

Comment: @Aram d'oh, thanks, that was quite obvious ;)

Comment: it is 6 i have counted it on the text file here is a sample 14.594937-121.167735-1761-1-1/1/2015-OOA 01 0100H January 2015 MOL 20 fully armed members of CNN operating within AOR wearing military camouflage uniforms were sighted at the vicinity Sitio Calumpit Brgy Macabud Rodriguez wherein t

Comment: i thought it would be appropriate to attach a sample

Comment: And one more thing   in stead of doing this tblcsv.Rows.Add();
use DataRow dr = tblcsv.NewRow(), and then    dr[count] = FileRec; tblcsv.Rows.Add(dr).

Comment: Check the array's actual length, not the sample. The sample line may be correct but the actual  array will contain more than 6 columns. Check the input line that causes the issue, I bet you'll find an extra `-`

Comment: Please post the input line that causes the error. It's impossible to help if you don't.  I'll guess there is there is at least one dash in the `Details` field. If that's the case, you can't use `Split()`. If the field is quoted, a library like CsHelper can help. If not, you'll need something more powerful, eg a Regex

Comment: this is the line that gives the error  tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;

Comment: Please post the **input line** that causes the error. The contents of **csvRow**. You'll find an extra dash in there

Comment: i had to inspect the text file and indeed it had an extra dash sorry for bothering you guys a big thanks to everyone

Comment: If it was in the last line, you can use a regex to capture the first 5 fields, then capture the rest of the line as the `Details` field. This is definitely *not* a CSV file

Comment: it wasn't on the last line it was in the middle of a long string the sixth column thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your excel file might have more columns than 6 for one or more rows. For this reason the splitting in inner foreach finds more columns but the tblcsv does not have more columns than 6 to assign the extra column value.

Try something like this:

```
foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split('-'))
{
    if(count > 5)
        return;
    tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;
    count++;
}
```

However it would be better if you check for additional columns before processing and handle the issue.

Comment: This will add bad data to the table. Obviously, the line contains unexpected dashes, which means that one of the array cells will contain bad (truncated) data. This code will add the bad data without even a warning

Comment: Yes this approach will include bad data and should not be followed. Best thing is to handle the situation earlier and work accordingly. Using regular expression as described by @Panagiotis Kanavos is a very good work arround.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();   //// this will hold the record for those array which have length greater than the 6

foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
                    {
                        //Adding each row into datatable  
                       DataRow dr = tblcsv.NewRow(); and then  
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split('-'))
                        {
                     try
                      {
                           dr[count] = FileRec;
                            tblcsv.Rows.Add(dr);
                      }
                     catch (IndexOutOfRangeException i)
                     {
                     error.AppendLine(csvRow;)
                     break;
                     }
                            count++;
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Now in this case we will have the knowledge of the csv row which is causing the errors, and rest will be processed successfully. Validate the row in errors whether its desired input, if not then correct value in csv file.

Comment: Far easier to simply check the length of the array and just *not* add it. No reason to throw exceptions if you can do a simple check

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat the file as a CSV if the delimiter appears inside a field. In this case you can use a regular expression to extract the first five fields up to the dash, then read the rest of the line as the sixth field. With a regex you can match the entire string and even avoid splitting lines.

Regular expressions are also a lot faster than splits and consume less memory because they don't create temporary strings. That's why they are used extensively to parse log files. The ability to capture fields by name doesn't hurt either

The following sample parses the entire file and captures each field in a named group. The last field captures everything to the end of the line:

```
var pattern="^(?<latitude>.*?)-(?<longitude>.*?)-(?<mps>.*?)-(?<activity_type>.*?)-" +
            "(?<date_occured>.*?)-(?<detail>.*)$";
var regex=new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches=regex.Matches(forex);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    DataRow dr = tblcsv.NewRow();
    row["latitude"]=match.Groups["latitude"].Value);
    row["longitude"]=match.Groups["longitude"].Value);
    ...
    tblcsv.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

The `(?<latitude>.*?)-` pattern captures everything up to the first dash into a group named `latitude`. The `.*?` pattern means the matching isn't greedy ie it won't try to capture everything to the end of the line but will stop when the first `-` is encountered.

The column names match the field names, which means you can add all fields with a loop:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var row = tblCsv.NewRow();
    foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in tblCsv.Columns)
        {
            row[col.ColumnName]=match.Groups[col.ColumnName].Value;                        
        }                    
    }
    tblCsv.Rows.Add(row);
}
tblCsv.Rows.Add(row);
```